# Malformed JSON: Expected '{'

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, webservices, json

I resolved this issue my changing res.setBody('123') as json thanks to all
I am trying to deserialize as follows:

```
webservice static void RESTApiToAccount(id AccountId)
{
    String clientId = 'XXXX';
    String clientSecret = 'XXX';
    String username = 'XXX';
    String password = 'XXXX';
    String reqbody = 'grant_type=password&client_id='+clientId+'&client_secret='+clientSecret+'&username='+username+'&password='+password;
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setBody(reqbody);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setEndpoint('https://ap4.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
    SendAccountUsingRESTAPI resp1 = (SendAccountUsingRESTAPI)JSON.deserialize(res.getbody(),SendAccountUsingRESTAPI.class);

    String accessToken;
    accessToken = resp1.access_token;
    if(accessToken != null)
    {
    String endPoint = 'https://ap4.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Account';
    JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
    Account a=[select id,name,website from account where id=:AccountId];
    gen.writeStartObject();
    gen.writeStringField('name', a.name);
    gen.writeStringField('id', a.id);
    gen.writeStringField('website', a.website);
    String s=gen.getasString();
    Http h2 = new Http();
    HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
    req1.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + accessToken);
    req1.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    req1.setHeader('accept','application/json');
    req1.setBody(s);

    req1.setMethod('POST');
    req1.setEndpoint(endPoint);
    HttpResponse res1 = h2.send(req1);
    String trimmedResponse = res1.getBody();
    system.debug('sasasasa'+res1);
    system.debug('@@@RESPONSE@@'+trimmedResponse);
    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res1.getBody());
}
```

I am getting this error when trying to use a mock call:

> Malformed JSON: Expected '{' at the beginning of object

What should I be doing to deserialize my data?

```
@isTest
static void myTest() { // Set mock callout class 
    Test.startTest();

    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());

    Account a=new account();
    a.name='test';
    a.website='www.test.com';

    SendAccountUsingRESTAPI.RESTApiToAccount(a.id);

    Test.StopTest();
}
```

MockHttpResponseGenerator class:

```
@isTest
public class MockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {
    // Implement this interface method
    public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
             String endpoint = req.getEndpoint();
        if ( endpoint.contains('oauth2/token') ) {
            return buildOAuthResponse( req );
        } else if ( endpoint.contains('/services/apexrest/Account') ) {
            return buildShortenResponse( req );
        }
        return null;
    }
  private HttpResponse buildOAuthResponse( HttpRequest req ) {
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setBody('123');
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res;
    }
    private HttpResponse buildShortenResponse( HttpRequest req ) {

        // Create a fake response
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setBody('{"foo":"bar"}');       
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res;
    } 
}
```

Comment: problem is that during **res.setBody('123');** proper json is not being returned

Comment: Yup, just as kurunve said, if you debug res.getBody() you'll see that the json is malformed.  Instead of generating the response dynamically you can store it as a static resource and call it that way...

Comment: If I set the body  from res.setBody('123'); to res.setBody('{"foo":"bar"}'); it will pass but I can't get code coverage because access token will come null and will not enter the loop.Please find my updated question

Comment: @SalesforceLearner Is there a reason why you're choosing not to use SingleRequestMock() or MultiRequestMock()? [Testing Apex Callouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/03/testing-apex-callouts-using-httpcalloutmock.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any time I test deserialization, I feed directly serialized data into the system as my input. It's much easier to control and understand, especially with complex structures.

```
MyClass.SendAccountUsingRESTAPI data = new MyClass.SendAccountUsingRESTAPI();
data.access_token = '<some_value>';
response.setBody(JSON.serialize(data));
```

---

You may also find that this out of the box serialization process is more succinct for other objects as well, such as the `Account` record you included in your OP.

**Verbose**

```
JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
Account a=[select id,name,website from account where id=:AccountId];
gen.writeStartObject();
gen.writeStringField('name', a.name);
gen.writeStringField('id', a.id);
gen.writeStringField('website', a.website);
String s=gen.getasString();
```

**Succinct**

```
String s = JSON.serialize([SELECT Id, Name, Website FROM Account WHERE Id = :AccountId]);
```

Comment: Ah, and I thought I was the only one that was weird that way...